# Toggle Div Show/Hide

Tags: javascript, css, html, web, toggle

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ToggleList(IDS) {
        var CState = document.getElementById(IDS);
        if (CState.style.display != "block") { CState.style.display = "block"; }
        else { CState.style.display = "none"; }
    }

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .divInfo
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<p>Text</p>
<a onclick="ToggleList('LT3')">Show More</a>
</p>
<div id="LT3" class="divInfo">
<p>Additional Test</p>
</div>
```

This works great, but I'd love to have the label "Show More" change to "Hide" when the toggle is expanded. Any ideas on how to do that? CState.innertext = "Hide" ?

Comment: `innerText` won't work on all browsers and neither will `textContent` but you can use both in tandem, alternatively using `innerHTML` will work on all but it is a slight more taxing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CState object in your function is a reference to the DIV.  What you should do is give the anchor tag an ID, and then change the text inside of that.

```
function ToggleList(anchorID, IDS) {
    var CState = document.getElementById(IDS);
    var anchor = document.getElementByID(anchorID);

    if (CState.style.display != "block") {
        CState.style.display = "block";
        anchor.innerHTML = "Hide";
    } else {
       CState.style.display = "none";
       anchor.innerHTML = "Show more";
    }
}
```

Your anchor tag would then look like this:

```
<a id="listToggle" onclick="ToggleList('listToggle', 'LT3')">Show More</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

To gain browser compatiblity, create a variable like this:

```
var text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
```

Then use it like this:

```
CState[text] = "New Text Content";
```

---

But it seems like you want to change the label of the `<a>`, not the `<div>`. So you'd do this to your HTML:

```
<a onclick="ToggleList(this, 'LT3')">Show More</a>
```

And then this to your JS:

```
var text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

function ToggleList(anchor, IDS) {
    var CState = document.getElementById(IDS);
    if (CState.style.display != "block") { 
        CState.style.display = "block";
        anchor[text] = "Hide";
    } else { 
        CState.style.display = "none"; 
        anchor[text] = "Show More";
    }
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/RRUEY/

Answer (score 1):

Pass a reference of the `<a>` to the function, then refactor the function a bit to re-tag it based on visibility:

```
function ToggleList(anchor,IDS) {
  var CState = document.getElementById(IDS);
  var isVisible = (CState.style.display == "block");

  anchor.innerHTML = isVisible ? 'Show more' : 'Hide';
  CState.style.display = isVisible ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

The altered HTML:

```
<a onclick="ToggleList(this,'LT3')">Show More</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will want to add an id to the  tag, for example:

```
<a id='txtShowMore' onclick="ToggleList('LT3')">Show More</a>
```

Then have this script:

```
var showMoreElement = document.getElementByID('txtShowMore');
showMoreElement.innerHTML = "Hide";
```

And then of course, the same thing for setting it back to "Show More" when you hide it.